In the first Harry Potter book, did Harry ever ask if his parents exist as ghosts?
In the book Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, did Harry ever ask about the possibility of his parents existing as ghosts? I was sure that he did, but I cannot find the scene in the book. Searching online annoying only points me to the fifth book.

There is no mention of it in the first book. Additionally, it is implied in the fifth book that he had not considered it. In Chapter Thirty-Eight, when trying to find out if Sirius could come back as a ghost, the following occurs:

But then an idea struck him.... A better idea than a mirror... A much bigger, more important idea... How had he never thought of it before — why had he never asked?

The word “never” seems to indicate that he is not just reflecting on why he hadn’t thought of it or asked about it in the short time since Sirius’s death, but why he hadn’t thought or asked about it in his entire time at Hogwarts.
